# Angular 5 Component getting too large

Tags: typescript, angular5

I am working on an Angular 5 app and one of our components file is getting massively large around thousand lines and growing… which will eventually be difficult to maintain and comprehend.

We are wondering how we could split it. That’s why any help/insight would be hugely appreciated.

The structure of the file is:

Class variables:

```
map: Map
jobs: Jobs[]
locations: Loc[]
building: Building[]
```

Methods: (the methods basically populate elements on the map)

The map variable is shared between all the methods and is used as a container.

```
loadData()
displayJobs(data: Jobs[]){
displayLocations(data: Jobs[])
createBuildings(data: Building[])
```

loadData -> Get all the data from the server and then this data is used in the different methods to plot it on the map.

We have a lot more methods with a similar approach they read the data fetched in the loadData and plot it on the map.

Is there any “correct” way to separate this methods into several files, components, don’t know?

To make this main component clearer and easier to maintain.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can refine this code. I'd suggest to build a service for each object (Job, Location, Building) and put the whole business logic in these services. Use the component, as far as possible, only for the presentation and interaction with the service. Thus, you'll shrink the size of your component enormously and you'll have a better maintainable code.

Comment: Hi @DiabolicWords, Thanks for answering. Alright, that sounds good. What I cannot see yet is: On the component I have controls by controls I mean (if there is bubbles opened on the map, jobs, technician). so there are a few variables that need to be shared between these services. How can I handle this?

Comment: @Aitor Molina all variables can be shared among components by using services

Comment: Even this you can handle inside a service. Something like an Intercommunication-Service which all the services inject. Here you can implement methods to share content among the services. This service is supposed to act like a MQ-Server. No own logic, just piping information from one service to the other. -- If this approach appears to be too complicated, just import the services into each other, But avoid circle dependencies.

Comment: Great, I am going to refactor the component code and try all this out. Thanks!.